# Odoo ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I am using Odoo 10 and I am trying to calculate a field. The calculation actually works but I get an error in Odoo and have to click OK to continue. After I click ok it works the error is

```
self.boxes = (self.squaremtr or 0.0) / (self.squarebox or 0.0)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Below is my code in python

```
@api.onchange('squaremtr')
    def _onchange_boxes(self):
        self.boxes = (self.squaremtr or 0.0) / (self.squarebox or 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot divide by zero (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero), it doesn't make mathematical sense. This also means you can't do `(self.squarebox or 0.0)`.

You have to check if self.squarebox is a valid number and handle it in some sensible way.

Answer (score 0):

We should take some test case to handle devision if it's division by zero.

Try with following code:

```
@api.onchange('squaremtr')
    def _onchange_boxes(self):
        if self.squaremtr and self.squarebox:
            self.boxes = self.squaremtr / self.squarebox
        elif self.squaremtr:
            self.boxes = self.squaremtr
        elif self.squarebox:
            self.boxes = self.squarebox
        else:
            self.boxes = 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is:

```
@api.onchange('squaremtr')
def _onchange_boxes(self):
    if self.squaremtr != 0 and self.squarebox != 0:
        self.boxes = self.squaremtr / self.squarebox
    else:
        self.boxes = 0.0
```